# Consecutive Square Numbers divided by Consecutive Odd Numbers

Tags: square-numbers

Why do we get this pattern (note what has been highlighted or italicized) when you divide consecutive square numbers with consecutive odd numbers ?

4 ÷ 3 = **1 R 1**

9 ÷ 5 = 1 R *4*

16 ÷ 7 = **2 R 2**

25 ÷ 9 = 2 R *7*

36 ÷ 11 = **3 R 3**

49 ÷ 13 = 3 R *10*

64 ÷ 15 = **4 R 4**

81 ÷ 17 = 4 R *13*

100 ÷ 19 = **5 R 5**

121 ÷ 21 = 5 R *16*

144 ÷ 23 = **6 R 6**

169 ÷ 25 = 6 R *19*

196 ÷ 27 = **7 R 7**

225 ÷ 29 = 7 R *22*

256 ÷ 31 = **8 R 8**

Answer (score 1):

Your observation (in the bold) is that $(2n)^2$ divided by $4n-1$ has the result $n$ **R** $n$.

$(2n)^2=4n^2$ and if you multiply the divisor $(4n-1)$ by the quotient $n$ and add the remainder $n$ you get $((4n-1)\cdot n)+n=4n^2-n+n=4n^2$.

So that pattern is just what you expect.

Your observation (in italics) is that $(2n+1)^2$ divided by $4n+1$ has the result $n$ **R** $(3n+1)$.

$(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$ and if you multiply the divisor $(4n+1)$ by the quotient $n$ and add the remainder $3n+1$ you get $((4n+1)\cdot n)+3n+1=4n^2+n+3n+1=4n^2+4n+1$.

So that pattern is just what you expect.